# Should I say "brings", "takes", "follows", or "leads" "us to a contradiction"?

Tags: transitivity

This text was written by [coffee1054](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/13752) in [this question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/42992/please-show-me-my-mistakes):

> You might feel that it is impossible for resistance to be strictly equal to
>   zero: maybe it _______ to some contradiction with Ohm's law.

How to say that something could involve a contradiction? What verb-phrase should go into the verb slot after "maybe it":

brings us  | takes us

or perhaps:

follows | leads

Comment: I'd say 'leads' but I can't justify why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [Tetsujin's comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/43001/brings-takes-follows-leads-us-to-a-contradiction-which-one-is-correct#comment79925_43001) **leads** is a good fit for the blank given. In general this formulation can be used to describe a logical implication - given the situation:

```
IF A THEN B
```

we can say "A leads to B" or alternatively, "B follows from A". For additional clarity or emphasis, the adverb 'logically' can be applied to the verb in question.

Given a little more latitude, you could also rewrite the second phrase (minus the colon) as:

> as it **implies** a contradiction to Ohm's law.

or

> as it **necessitates** a contradiction to Ohm's law.